# How to add a new attribute with multiple Values

Tags: api, acumatica, endpoint

I am trying with this script. I am able to add 1 attribute with 1 value, but how to add 1 attribute with multiple values.

```
{   
    "AttributeID": {"value": "NEWI15"},
    "Description": {"value": "TEMPORARY"},
    "ValueID": {"value": "1001"},
    "AttributeIDDescription": {"value": "AAA1"},
    "ControlType": {"value": "Combo"}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that you can achieve

```
{
"testobject":[
    "AttributeID": {"value": "NEWI15","value2":"somthing"},
    "Description": {"value": "TEMPORARY"},
    "ValueID": {"value": "1001"},
    "AttributeIDDescription": {"value": "AAA1"},
    "ControlType": {"value": "Combo"}
]
}
```